# How to make welcome window?

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode4, nswindow, popupwindow

I am creating an app in which i want to create one welcome window/view (I don't know exactly coz i am very new to cocoa development) something like this..

[image]

So when my app launches this welcome window display at top of the `mainWindow` and when i click any `Button` from this welcome window/view then and then i can perform any action on `mainWindow`.

Can anyone help me in this..??

Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Learn how to make a window appear/disappear. Look up `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` and `close:` in the documentation.
2. In your app delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, show the welcome window.
3. When the button is pressed, close the window.
4. There's no step 4!

---

That said, let me say my personal opinion. I don't like welcome windows, because it distracts from me doing the thing I like to do with your app. Not many apps have them. Those who have them always has a checkbox on it which says "don't show welcome window on launch". So, please implement them.

Comment: Thanks..!! i also agree with you but, after all i am a developer and i have to do what my client say.BTW if i put `welcomeWindow` in  `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` then still i can perform any action in my `mainwindow`. What i want is without clicking `welcomewinow`'s `OK` button user can't do anything in my app.

Comment: I understand your pain. But that's too obtrusive... can't you say to your client that it's impossible on OS X? If you do need to implement that, look for runModal in the documentation. If it's about your work, I can't help you unless you pay me part of your salary;)

Answer (score 0):

If You want to disable clicks in Your main window you should enable mouse ignoring:

```
[mainWindow setIgnoresMouseEvents:YES];
```

and when user clicks welcomewindow's OK button disable ignore mouse events:

```
[mainWindow setIgnoresMouseEvents:NO];
```

**where mainWindow is Your IBoutlet main window!